# How to remove array items in array 2 if the items doesnt match with items of array 1 and concat with array 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have two arrays:

```
project_users = [{
    username: "sam", name: "Sampath", email: "xyz" 
},{
    username: "ram", name: "Ram Mohan", email: "asd" 
},{
    username: "shyam", name: "Shyam pandey", email: "wer" 
}]

admin_users = [{
    username: "sam", name: "Sampath", email: "xyz" 
},{
    username: "pandey", name: "Mangal Pandey", email: "yuy" 
},{
    username: "ameer", name: "Gajini", email: "tyrt" 
},{
    username: "shyam", name: "Shyam pandey", email: "wer" 
}]
```

I want to create a new array with name `project_admin_user` who are project users list present under admin users.

Expected result:

```
project_admin_users = [{
    username: "sam", name: "Sampath", email: "xyz" 
},{
    username: "shyam", name: "Shyam pandey", email: "wer" 
}]
```

How can I achieve this in Angular (preferred) or jQuery?

Comment: **[`admin_users.filter(o => project_users.find(p => p.username === o.username));`](https://jsfiddle.net/239ccmka/)**. **Note:** will work on latest browsers only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here solution:

```
project_admins=project_users.filter(function(val){ 

  return admin_users.find( function(val2){ 
    return val.username===val2.username 
  });

});
```

This is pure js ECMAScript 5 solution, check browsers compatibility- http://caniuse.com/#search=forEach

Comment: No problem @SampathReddy. Good luck to You.

Comment: Note: `array.find` has compatibility issues. Check it before using it

Comment: @MaciejSikora this solution do not work when many users have the same `username`.. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `admin_users` array; returning those users that were found in the `project_users` array with the method [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var project_users = [{username: "sam",name: "Sampath",email: "xyz"}, {username: "ram",name: "Ram Mohan",email: "asd"}, {username: "shyam",name: "Shyam pandey",email: "wer"}],
    admin_users = [{username: "sam",name: "Sampath",email: "xyz"}, {username: "pandey",name: "Mangal Pandey",email: "yuy"}, {username: "ameer",name: "Gajini",email: "tyrt"}, {username: "shyam",name: "Shyam pandey",email: "wer"}];

var project_admin_users = admin_users.filter(function(admin) {
    return project_users.find(function(user) {
        return JSON.stringify(admin) === JSON.stringify(user);
    });
});

console.log(project_admin_users);
```

Note that are compared all properties of the two objects with [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: yes if username will be the same then it will not work, but comparing long strings like you offered has poor performance. Comparing big data, object or strings is not good solution. Best is comparing ID fields, but in example was none ID field so I choosed most appropriate field - username. Good luck to You!

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this;

```js
Object.prototype.compare = function(o){
  var ok = Object.keys(this);
  return typeof o === "object" && ok.length === Object.keys(o).length ? ok.every(k => this[k] === o[k]) : false;
};
Array.prototype.compare = function(a){
  return this.every((e,i) => typeof a[i] === "object" ? a[i].compare(e) : a[i] === e);
};

Array.prototype.intersect = function(a) {
  return this.filter(to => a.some(ao => ao.compare(to)));
};

var project_users = [{username : "sam", name:"Sampath", email:"xyz" },
                     {username : "ram", name:"Ram Mohan", email:"asd" },
                     {username : "shyam", name:"Shyam pandey", email:"wer" }
                    ],
      admin_users = [{username : "sam", name:"Sampath", email:"xyz" },
                     {username : "pandey", name:"Mangal Pandey", email:"yuy" },
                     {username : "ameer", name:"Gajini", email:"tyrt" },
                     {username : "shyam", name:"Shyam pandey", email:"wer" }
                    ];
   project_admins = admin_users.intersect(project_users);
console.log(JSON.stringify(project_admins,0,4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```js
project_users = [{username : "sam", name:"Sampath", email:"xyz" },
{username : "ram", name:"Ram Mohan", email:"asd" },
{username : "shyam", name:"Shyam pandey", email:"wer" }]

admin_users = [{username : "sam", name:"Sampath", email:"xyz" },
{username : "pandey", name:"Mangal Pandey", email:"yuy" },
{username : "ameer", name:"Gajini", email:"tyrt" },
{username : "shyam", name:"Shyam pandey", email:"wer" }] 

project_admin_users=[];

admin_users.forEach(function(val){ 
 if (project_users.find( function(val2){ return val.name===val2.name; })) project_admin_users.push(val); 
 });
alert(JSON.stringify(project_admin_users));
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine project_user and admin_user into project_admin_user array and pass the value to removeDuplicate().

```js
 function removeDuplicate(proj_admin_user) {
        var destObjects = {};

        for (var i=proj_admin_user.length - 1;i>=0;i--) {
              var item =JSON.stringify([proj_admin_user[i].username, proj_admin_user[i].name,proj_admin_user[i].email]);                   
          
            if (destObjects[item]) {
                proj_admin_user.splice(i, 1);

            } else {
                destObjects[item] = true;          
            }
        }

        return proj_admin_user;

    }

    var proj_admin_user = [{username : "sam", name:"Sampath", email:"xyz" },
    {username : "pandey", name:"Mangal Pandey", email:"yuy" },
    {username : "ameer", name:"Gajini", email:"tyrt" },
    {username : "shyam", name:"Shyam pandey", email:"wer" },
    {username : "sam", name:"Sampath", email:"xyz" }] ;
    var clean = removeDuplicate(proj_admin_user);
```